# SCSS function with for loop inside not working

Tags: css, function, for-loop, sass

I'm trying to write a function that creates a grid layout based on multiple arrangements (as opposed to just the 12 column grid) in Sass (scss syntax). The for loop inside works properly on its own, but when I wrap it in a function it no longer works. I'm new to using Sass functions, so maybe I'm messing up the syntax? Or is this just not possible? I'm just trying to avoid having to write a new for loop for each layout I want to achieve. Thanks in advance.

```
@function create-grid($num-cols) {
  @for $col from 1 through $num-cols {
    .col-#{$col}-of-#{$num-cols} {
      width: percentage($col / $num-cols);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sass functions return a value.

If you want to generate css programatically like this, you want to use a mixin.

https://www.sitepoint.com/sass-basics-the-mixin-directive/

```
@mixin grid($num-cols) {
  @for $col from 1 through $num-cols {
    .col-#{$col}-of-#{$num-cols} {
      width: percentage($col / $num-cols);
    }
  }
}

@include grid(12)
```

Comment: Wow, thank you. I saw that I could use functions in Sass and went straight for it without reading about mixins.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who stumbles across this post, the final product is:

```
@mixin create-grid($num-cols, $col-gutter) {
  @for $col from 1 through $num-cols {
    .col-#{$col}-of-#{$num-cols} {
      width: calc(
        ((100% - ((#{$num-cols} - 1) * #{$col-gutter})) / #{$num-cols}) *
          #{$col} +
          ((#{$col} - 1) * #{$col-gutter})
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks a lot to @HorusKol for introducing me to the world of mixins!